# Tracing the action of consuming messages from mailbox in Erlang

Tags: erlang, actor, trace

I went through the documentation of the `trace/3` BIF in Erlang.  However, one observation I have made is that it cannot be used for tracing the consuming of messages from the mailbox.  The flag `'receive'` only traces when messages are added to a process's mailbox.

Is there any way one can trace events such as reading from the mailbox using the `receive` construct?  If not, is there any reason why this isn't possible?  It seems very strange that one can trace most kind of events in a program and the reading of messages from a mailbox is not traceable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool. You can only hope for call tracing of the handling function. It is rather easy in OTP applications since you can hook `handle_...`.