# Can match specifications be used when tracing messages in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, trace

When tracing function calls in Erlang match specifications can be used to narrow down the set of function calls generating trace messages.

- Is there a way to use match specifications to filter out messages
  when tracing sent or received messages?

I've read the docs for `dbg` and `ttb` and also found this [presentation](http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/316/dbg[1].pdf) by Mazen Harake from Erlang Solutions useful when learning about tracing.

When searching with Google almost all examples I've found trace function calls not sending or receiving messages.

- Maybe tracing messages is not considered useful by most Erlang programmers?

My question may be loosely related to the questions ["Tracing the action of consuming messages from mailbox in Erlang"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630225/tracing-the-action-of-consuming-messages-from-mailbox-in-erlang).

Comment: As @i-give-crap-answers explains in the accepted answer, using match specifications when tracing messages is not possible. My curiosity makes me want to understand why this functionality is not supported. Is it simply not implemented (yet) or are there some technical reasons I don't fully understand (yet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it, but:

- You can send every message to a tracer and then clean them out there by a filter. For low-rate messaging with fairly small messages, this might work well.
- You can use the seq_tracer features and then match on  a function call which then invokes the seq_tracer on the process. This would be able to cut down the amount of trace messages as well.

Comment: Yes, manually filter trace messages is a possibility but I hoped there was a more efficient options similar to using match specifications when tracing function calls. Thanks @i-give-crap-answers, I spent quite some time trying to search for an answer and can now stop searching.

Comment: I will look in to seq_tracer but after a quick look it doesn't seem to fit my current needs.